# Squiggly arrow in xypic giving error in LyX

Tags: lyx, xy-pic

I am trying to compile `\xymatrix{A\ar@{\sim>}[r] & B}` in LyX and I get the following error message:
[image]

How can I fix this? The code compiles in ERT, just not in the native xypic mathmode.

Here is a [link to MWE.lyx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iah3fvuedyjowk9/MWE.lyx?dl=0)

Comment: `\sim` is mathmode. Try replacing it for a tilde `~`

Comment: @JJMDriessen didn't work either. Exactly the same errors.

Comment: I've added some MWE code in the answer below that doesn't produce the error.

Comment: @Exterior can you please post an MWE .lyx file? Please read http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @scottkosty added a link.

Comment: @Exterior I took a look but it does not seem to be a MWE. There is a complicated preamble, loading many packages. And is the language required to be in Hebrew to reproduce? If you remove those unnecessary settings and post a MWE I will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the xypic package requires some special characters (in particular the tilde ~), which is automatically rewritten by the math editor in LyX. It is somewhat cumbersome to make LyX insert a true tilde into the source code.

But this is a case where the LyX "Macro" feature comes in handy.

1. Go to *Insert* -> *Math* -> *Macro*.
2. Write `\sqarrow` instead of `\newmacroname`.
3. Then you copy the text `\ar@{~>}[r]`, and paste it directly into the *TeX* field of the LyX macro.
4. Finally, in the *LyX* field of the macro, enter some symbol that resemble the output symbol, such as `~~>` or `\rightarrow`.

You have now created a macro `\sqarrow` for the squiggly arrow, which you can use directly in the LyX math editor.

For the record, LyX rewrites this macro as `\global\long\def\sqarrow{\ar@{~>}[r]}` in the LaTeX source code.

Comment: If you think this is a bug in LyX (or you have an idea for how LyX can do this better), please open a ticket at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: Actually, this issue is just now being discussed in the lyx-devel mailing list. As for today, there is no convenient way of inserting pure tex code into the LyX math editor.

Comment: Ah I did not realize that was the same issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

The shape input of `\xymatrix` in `\ar@{shape}[direction]` does not use mathmode and uses its own interpreter to recognize types of arrow shapes. The input is independent of the environment, and works both in textmode and mathmode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy} % include cmtip or your arrow will be ugly

\begin{document}
\xymatrix{A\ar@{~>}[r] & B}

\begin{equation}
\xymatrix{A\ar@{~>}[r] & B}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, now I see that the problem is actually with LyX. If I write the code in ERT then it works, but it won't compile within the native xypic framework. Can you help me solve this?

Comment: @Exterior. I don't use LyX. Maybe checking out chapter 1 & 2 from this document would help: http://wiki.lyx.org/uploads/Examples/XY-pic/xypic.pdf Did you include the `preview` package?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it seems to be a very specific error. All other arrows and diagrams work well for me... :(